# Having a string with two quotes around it?

Tags: python

How can I have a string like "'1'"? I have tried:

> a = str(str(1))

but result still is '1'.

Comment: a = '""1""' (a = single quote double quote double quote 1 double quote double quote single quote)

Comment: if you want to treat `"` als literal character, simply create the string using single quotes -  or use triple single/double quotes: `a = ' " " a " " '`  or `a = ''' " " a " " '''` or `a = """ " " a " " """`    (delete the spaces)

Comment: What do you mean by two quotes? Do you want two single-quotes (apostrophes) or two double-quotes (quote characters)? You can [edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 3):

Use escape sequence:

`print("\"\"1\"\"")`

```
>> print("\"\"1\"\"")
""1""
```

BTW, this method is used by many people hence this is preferable :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add those characters to your string using placeholders, doing so:
`a = '"%s"'% a`

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes inside a double quoted string as mentioned above: "'1'" or '"1"' or you can escape quotes like '\'1\'' or "\"1\"". See for example [Python Escape Characters](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
def single_quoted(s):
    return "'" + s + "'"

def double_quoted(s):
    return '"' + s + '"'

a = double_quoted(single_quoted(str(1)))
print(a)
```

It is very verbose so you can see what each individual part does, without inspecting your code carefully to find where each `'` and `"` is. The output is

```
"'1'"
```

---

By the way, maybe you actually need this:

```
a = single_quoted(str(1))
print(a)
```

This outputs

```
'1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use func call as you ask; try this solution:

```
str('\"1\"')
```